# Why was Ueda Ryouhei appointed the head of the Yoshioka clan and not Seijuurou's son?

Tags: vagabond

I am reading the manga Vagabond. After the death of Yoshioka Denshichirou, someone named Ueda Ryouhei is appointed as the head of the family. Ryouhei then makes a decision that the school should fight Musashi near Ichijou-ji Temple outside Kyoto.

But according to [an answer on History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/8395/739), it was the 12-year-old son of Seijuurou's, Yoshioka Matashichiro, doing this. Is Ueda Ryuhei a fictional character that has replaced Yoshioka Matashichiro? If so, why did the author not show Yoshioka Matashichiro in his comic?

Answer (score 4):

*Vagabond* is a fictionalized interpretation of Musashi's life adapted from Eiji Yoshikawa's *Musashi*. The novel is a dramatization and not really historically accurate, even though many people have started to take Yoshikawa's book as historical due to it's popularity.

Now why was there no mention of Matashichiro, the youngest of the Yoshioka brothers? It's better (commercially) to not to mention the fact that Musashi killed a 12 year old boy.

Comment: Has the author commented anything about ommitting the character anywhere ?